# Not allowing to add or update any numeric or decimal value once it reach upto two decimal

Tags: javascript, jquery, validation

I need to restrict the user for following things:

1) only allow numeric
2) decimal upto 2 digits
3) allow - backspace, tab,delete buttons

Below code is working fine except one scenario,
Problem is, (Example) when textbox input reach as `6545.12` then after try to change the value as below `65457.12` or `7545.13` then it does not allow and just restrict me.  (so, here, not allowing to add new digit or change the existing digit before `.` or after `.`)

Can any one please guide me how to solve this issue.

calling below function on `keypress` event of textbox.

```
        function isNumber(evt, element) {

        var charCode = (evt.which) ? evt.which : event.keyCode

        if (
          &&      // “-” CHECK MINUS, AND ONLY ONE.
            (charCode != 8) && (charCode != 9) && (charCode != 37) && (charCode != 39) &&
            (charCode != 46 || $(element).val().indexOf('.') != -1) &&      // “.” CHECK DOT, AND ONLY ONE.
            (charCode < 48 || charCode > 57)) {

            return false;
        }
        if ($(element).val().indexOf('.') != -1)
        {
            var index = $(element).val().indexOf('.');
            var len = $(element).val().length;
            var CharAfterdot = (len + 1) - index;

            if (CharAfterdot <= 3) {
                return true;
            }
            else {
                return false;
            }


        }
        return true;
    }
```

Comment: Don't work with the event, check if the new value fits and if not, set the input's value to the old value.

Comment: can yo please share any example.

Answer (score 0):

You might consider including a library that implements input masking (that is, only allowing certain kinds of values to be entered into an input field). Using a library like https://github.com/RobinHerbots/jquery.inputmask you can specify a regular expression as a mask. An example regular expression that only allows numbers up to two decimal places would be `[0-9]+(\.[0-9][0-9]?)?`. After including the masking library you can either call the mask directly on the element or add a `data-inputmask-regex` property to your input. See https://github.com/RobinHerbots/jquery.inputmask#usage for more.

Short version: this is a hard problem and other people have already done the work.